# Unable to accept the privacy policy from Pycharm on Raspberry Pi

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, pycharm

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI1Ux.jpg)I have installed PyCharm(2020.3.1) on my Raspberry Pi (Kuhnbus RevPi3). When I start PyCharm the privacy policy window is displayed for acceptance. The problem is that the window is just a grey field without text, checkboxes, etc, which keeps me from accepting the policy and starting PyCharm.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with PyCharm on the Pi? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: maybe you can share the pop up to clarify your problem.

Comment: I put a screenshot of the pop up in my initial question...